# How to show TitleBar?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, titlebar

Something went wrong, and at one moment I lose TitleBar on the MainActivity. Theme applied Apptheme withon mark "NoActionBar". Could you help me to return it? activity_main.xml, AndroidManifest.xml and styles.xml are down the text. Thanks for any help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:collapseColumns="2">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
            android:src="@drawable/webcam"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:onClick="camact" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/glasses"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:onClick="slopes"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:src="@drawable/bed"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/food"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_column="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:src="@drawable/card"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/weather" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="xyz.crazyk0t.bydalsfjallen" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"
              android:label="@string/title_activity_main2">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Main3Activity"
              android:label="@string/title_activity_main3">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Main4Activity"
              android:label="@string/title_activity_main4" >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Main5Activity"
              android:label="@string/title_activity_main5">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Main6Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main6">
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/background_dark</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: can you post the manifest?

Comment: it's in second code post

Comment: now you want to have title bar? right?

Comment: I can't see why MainActivity "lost" actionbar...Where did you use the `AppTheme.NoActionBar`?

Comment: Your `MainActivity` extends `Activity` class but you're styling it with `Theme.Compat.Light.DarkActionBar` - these do not work together.

Comment: Aragaer, it really append to work, i'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity must extend `AppCompatActivity` not `Activity`, if you use themes from `Theme.AppCompat.*`

Answer (score 0):

Getting controlled by

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

To get back the title bar-

```
<item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
```

Comment: that gives action bar without title, sorry, it isn't that i need